# R loop for Phi coefficient

Tags: r, loops

I want to perform Phi function pairwise on each column of my dataframe.

This is how it looks like my df

```
AnxietyDisorders    ASD AutoimmuneThyroiditis   CeliacDisease
no  no  yes no
yes no  no  no
no  no  no  no
no  no  no  no
no  no  no  no
no  no  no  no
yes no  no  no
no  no  no  no
no  no  no  yes
```

To perform Phi coefficient normally I should perform:

```
Phi(df[,1],df[,2]
```

How can I put it in a loop to perform the Phi coefficient for variables pairwise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `combn`

```
combn(df, 2, FUN = function(x) Phi(x[,1], x[,2]))
```