# calculating a correlation coefficient for a binary variable in r

Tags: r, binary, correlation

```
Dataframe1: group "N"
ID  A   B   score
1   pos pos AB
1   neg pos B
2   neg neg Neg
3   neg pos B
4   neg neg Neg
5   neg neg Neg
5   pos neg A
5   neg pos B


Combined dataframe
    AB  A   B   Neg
N   440 54  67  345
O   3   6   56  543
P   23  25  3   765
R   4   5   67  243
```

I have 4 cohorts (NOPR) which have pairs of tests (A and B). All have had both A and B tested. Some are positive on both test (AB), some are positive only on one test (A or B). I want to answer the two questions: 
1. By how much does testing A increase the yield of potential positives for each cohort? 
2. How often do A and B correlate for each cohort?

In order to analyse the correlation between the tests (AB) I have tried the calculate a Phi Coefficient. I have followed the suggestion in this other post by @akrun, but was unable to get this to work.

[R loop for Phi coefficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379978/r-loop-for-phi-coefficient)

```
combn(df, 2, FUN = function(x) Phi(x[,1], x[,2]))
```

Any suggestions for how I can calculate this?

Comment: You say "but was unable to get this to work". Could you please elaborate on what exactly is not working?

Comment: I followed this previous post suggestion by @akrun couldn't get this command to work, despite downloading multiple packages which include the command for Phi.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because your data is not organized the same way. Each line of your data is a complete 2x2 table. Use `dput` to put your data in a format that we can easily read. Then we can cut/paste it:

```
dta <- structure(list(AB = c(440L, 3L, 23L, 4L), A = c(54L, 6L, 25L, 
5L), B = c(67L, 56L, 3L, 67L), Neg = c(345L, 543L, 765L, 243L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("N", "O", "P", "R"))
dfa
#    AB  A  B Neg
# N 440 54 67 345
# O   3  6 56 543
# P  23 25  3 765
# R   4  5 67 243
```

The first row of dfa is a table so for N:

```
N <- matrix(unlist(dfa[1, ]), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(A=c("Pos", "Neg"), B=c("Pos", "Neg")))
N
#      B
# A     Pos Neg
#   Pos 440  54
#   Neg  67 345
```

We can use `apply` to get all of the Phi coefficients:

```
apply(dfa, 1, function(x) Phi(matrix(x, 2)))
#          N          O          P          R 
# 0.73028594 0.09784794 0.63669678 0.09088293
```